# Overriding Windows cmd internal commands

Tags: windows, command-line, path

I'm using a program which uses the `type` command to pipe contents of a file to another program like this:

```
type test.txt | (another program)
```

This command is hardcoded in my main program. The problem is that the `type` command has problems with forward slashes:

```
E:\babak\git\bin>type e:/babak/git/bin/test.txt
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Is there a way to override the cmd internal `type` with a custom application named `type`, which supports forward slashes, so if someone calls `type` in cmd, the custom `type` application is called?

Comment: The ComSpec environment variable has the path to the command processor, default is c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe.  Use the SET command to substitute it with your own.

Comment: Have you tried to by pass the **type** command? Such as: **another_program < E:/babak/git/bin/test.txt**

Comment: The TYPE command works just fine with forward slashes if the argument is enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TYPE internal command will work fine with quotes if you enclose the argument in quotes.

```
type "e:/babak/git/bin/test.txt"
```

You can prevent use of an internal command and force use of a batch or exe if you quote the command:

```
"type" e:/babak/git/bin/test.txt
```

You can also include path info to force use of an exe or batch

```
E:\babak\git\bin\type e:/babak/git/bin/test.txt
```

or

```
.\type e:/babak/git/bin/test.txt
```

But if you do not have control over how the program invokes TYPE, then I don't see how you can use any of the above techniques.

The only other option I can think of is to preprocess your path info to convert the forward slashes into backslashes. Then you need to make sure your program gets the modifed path info.

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question

Comment: @kres0345 - It absolutely answers the question to the extent that it can be answered. TYPE is an internal command within cmd.exe. I show how to issue a TYPE command that bypasses the internal command in favor of any executeable of your choosing. But I agree that it is of little use to the OP when dealing with existing code. Passing the file name in quotes likely solves the problem, but doesn't answer the question in the title. The only other option is to modify the pre-existing code.

Comment: Oh, I misread parts of your answer, I agree that it answers the question, but evidently it can be answered further. @mosh showed a method addressing a method for *overriding* internal commands.

Answer (score 3):

You can use doskey to override internal cmds in command.com, e.g. on win7

```
c:\> date
  The current date is: Mon 09/18/2017
   Enter the new date: (mm-dd-yy)

c:\>   @doskey date=c:\cygwin\bin\date.exe $*
c:\>   @doskey echo=c:\cygwin\bin\echo.exe $*     

c:\> date +%Y-%m-%d
2017-09-18
```

Comment: How do you make doskey persistent?

Comment: @Greg Start cmd like this: cmd  "/k c:\aliases.txt"  and put doskey commands in  c:\aliases.txt

Comment: This only works on the command line in the simplest of cases. But doskey is of no use for the OP because doskey macros cannot be used with pipes, FOR /F, or within batch scripts.

Answer (score 1):

cmd.exe is just a program that resides in the System32 (or whatever) directory. If you replace it with a new cmd.exe then that one will be run instead whenever a user runs cmd.

There will be permission issues to be solved before replacing the file, but not impossible.

Comment: perhaps you could write a batch file/program that converts the string to the correct format then calls cmd itself with the new string. If you place that new program in a path that is checked before it gets to the "real" cmd perhaps that'll work.