# How to use Cygwin version of find rather than Windows version

Tags: windows, cmd, cygwin

I have got Cygwin installed in my machine and set its bin folder in my PATH.

I can use all the Cygwin commands in the Windows command prompt.

However, one problem I encountered is that both Cygwin an Windows have a command "`find`". Whenever I use `find`, the Windows version is picked up.

Is there anyway I can force using the Cygwin version of `find` rather than the Windows version?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the the cygwin executables folder `/usr/bin` is ahead of the cmd executables folder `c:\Windows\system32` in the PATH variable for both the cmd and bash shells to be sure you run cygwin's find instead of windows's find command.

Use `which -a find` in the cygwin shell to list executable files found via the bash shell's PATH variable.

Use `where $PATH:find` in cmd shell to list executable files found via the cmd shell's PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

**1**.Check what your paths are to the find.exe file, You will get a path for both Windows and Cygwin, with Windows being the first :

```
C:\Users\User>where find
C:\Windows\System32\find.exe
C:\cygwin64\bin\find.exe
```

**2**.Now you will see what the default operating system is:

```
`which find
C:\Windows\System32\find.exe`
```

**3**use this command to set find from Cygwin befor Windows:

```
set PATH=C:\cygwin64\bin;%PATH%
```

**4**.You will now see a long list of paths, and your path should be the first

```
C:\Users\User\L>echo %PATH%
```

**5**.Now you can do a short test to check if it works by a simple find command like:

```
`find . -type f -name *.txt`
```

If the operation returns all the files that end in txt, or it returns nothing (because you don't have any files that end like that in the current location) You made it! If you encounter the error again, check the steps .

Answer (score -1):

This is because find is a shell built-in in cmd, so it doesn't even try to go through the executable search path.

In general Cygwin symlinks will not be understood by Windows, but as explained https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#pathnames-symlinks it *is* possible in modern Windows versions to create native Windows symlinks on NTFS file systems, as long as the link doesn't cross file systems.

I would consider instead just wrapping it in, say, a batch script placed in your Cygwin `/usr/local/bin` with a name like `cygfind.bat` (or whatever you want to call it) that explicitly calls Cygwin's `find` by `C:\path\to\find.exe`.

The wrapper approach has the advantage that if you upgrade Cygwin and `find` is updated, the batch script wrapping it will still work transparently.

I've never tried it myself but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46282411/982257) you can also use the special `@doskey` variable to override cmd builtins.